Two brothers got separated
What's the movie were a mother left her two boys in a hotel and the youngest got lost. They found him in like 10 years. The woman who adopted him was in the hotel when she saw him. When the two brothers seen each other, the older kinda hated him because he's given so much attention. I remember them playing basketball and the part when the older gives him a stuffed toy while he was sleeping. 
Those were the parts that I remember. I think I watched it 6 years ago but I think the movie is much older.

I think you're after The Deep End of the Ocean from 1999 with Michelle Pfeiffer and Whoopi Goldberg:   

The Deep End of The Ocean is a film about a family's reaction when Ben, the youngest son is kidnapped and then found ten years later, living in the same town. 

The brothers play basketball and I think the aforementioned toy is a rabbit doll. Here's the trailer:



